# Create methods under / using CF for API Gateway

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

How do I create methods under API Gateway's root / folder using CF?  So for example I have a Gateway that looks like the following:

/
OPTIONS
POST

[image]

However when trying to do that with CF I get:
Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the beginning and the end.  So my PathPart is the offending line.

```
  ApiGate:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt 
        - ApiGateApi
        - RootResourceId
      PathPart: '{/}'
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateApi
```

I can change the PathPart to something else but then it creates it as a child object under / which is what I don't want.

[image]

Comment: Empty string?  Or perhaps `{}`?

Comment: I have tried both of those unfortunately.  Braces result in:Value of property PathPart must be of type String.  And when I use an empty string: [/Resources/ApiGatewayResource/Type/PathPart/] 'null' values are not allowed in templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after adding the following to my `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` it works now.

```
  MyMethodOPTIONS:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !GetAtt MyRestApi.RootResourceId
```

Here is more context into my Template:

```
  ApiGatewayMethodOPTIONS:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      ResourceId: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: OPTIONS
      Integration:
        Type: MOCK
        IntegrationResponses:
          - ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            ResponseTemplates:
              application/json: ''
            StatusCode: '200'
        PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
        RequestTemplates:
          application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: Empty
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
          StatusCode: '200'
```

```
  ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      ApiKeySourceType: HEADER
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Name: SearchAPI
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to what solved this? Maybe some more context of the surrounding CloudFormation content.

Comment: I've added more of my template to the original solution

Answer (score 0):

This fixes my problem, in my case I needed to have 2 methods:
1. will respond to requests to root e.g. `https://<api-url>/prod` or `https://<api-url>/prod/`.  This will use the RootResourceId of the API Gateway:

> ResourceId: !GetAtt myApiGateway.RootResourceId

2. this will respond to requests to whatever has been set under `https://<api-url>/prod/`.  Could be `petstore` or if using `{proxy+}` then the backend workload will try to resolve the request. It will refer to the Resource type defined in the template:

> ResourceId: !Ref myResource